# How to generate a random name in Ruby

Tags: ruby, random

I need to make a program in ruby to generate a robot name like KU765 or NG274 style
and to store them and check it to avoid repetition.
I also need to make a "reset" method to delete all stored names and start again.
This program is not working for some reason. I hope somebody helps me to find the mistake.
Thanks a lot.

```
class Robot
  attr_accessor :named , :stored_names , :rl
  def self.name
    new.name
  end

  @@rl = "_ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"

  def name
    named = ""
    named << @@rl[rand(26).to_i]
    named << @@rl[rand(26).to_i]
    named << rand(100..999).to_s
    named.save_name 
    named.check_name
  end

  def save_name
    stored_names = []
    stored_names << named
  end

  def check_name
    stored_names.uniq!
  end

  def reset
    stored_names = Array.new
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def save_name
  stored_names = []
  stored_names << named
end
```

Every time, you create a name, and call `save_name` you delete all previously created names, by assigning an empty array to `stored_names`

**EDIT:**
There were a few more errors, let me first post a working solution:

```
class Robot
  attr_accessor :named , :stored_names , :rl

  def initialize()
    @stored_names = []
  end

  @@rl = "_ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".chars.to_a

  def name
    @named = ""
    @named << @@rl.sample
    @named << @@rl.sample
    @named << rand(100..999).to_s
    save_name 
    check_name
  end

  def save_name
    @stored_names << @named
  end

  def check_name
    @stored_names.uniq!
  end

  def reset
    @stored_names = Array.new
  end
end
```

- To access the members of your object, you have to prefix them with `@`.
- You called `save_name` and `check_name` on `@named`, which is a string and doesn't provide these methods
- `@stored_names` must be initialized to an empty array, before you can push elements into it with `<<`. This is normally done in the class's constructor `initialize()`

Comment: yes, it is true, nice one, but still not working properly. It is something about how methods has been delcared.

Comment: You know that instead of `@@rl[rand(26).to_i]` you can use `Array#sample` or if `_` isn't needed then `rand('A'..'Z')`?

Comment: Nice catch, I didn't knew about Array#sample, I'll edit it, since it really does make the code more readable

Answer (score 3):

Here's another way to construct the `Robot` class that you may wish to consider. (My answers are not normally this long or detailed, but I wrote this in part to clarify aspects of Ruby's object model in my own mind. I hope it might help others do the same.)

**Code**

```
PREFACE      = ('A'..'Z').to_a << ?_
SUFFIX       = ('0'..'9').to_a
PREFACE_SIZE = 2
SUFFIX_SIZE  = 3

class Robot
  def self.reset()     @bots = []               end
  reset    
  def self.new()       (@bots << super).last    end
  def self.bots()      @bots                    end
  def self.delete(bot) @bots.delete(bot)        end
  def self.bot_names() @bots.map { |b| b.name } end

  attr_reader :name

  def initialize()     @name = add_name         end

  private

  def add_name
    loop do
      @name = gen_name 
      return @name unless self.class.bot_names.include?(@name)
    end
  end

  def gen_name
    PREFACE.sample(PREFACE_SIZE).join << SUFFIX.sample(SUFFIX_SIZE).join
  end
end
```

**Example**

```
Robot.bots           #=> []
robbie = Robot.new   #=> #<Robot:0x000001019f4988 @name="AP436">
robbie.name          #=> "AP436"
Robot.bots           #=> [#<Robot:0x000001019f4988 @name="AP436">]
r2d2 = Robot.new     #=> #<Robot:0x000001019cd450 @name="KL628">
r2d2.name            #=> "KL628"
Robot.bots           #=> [#<Robot:0x000001019f4988 @name="AP436">,
                     #   #<Robot:0x000001019cd450 @name="KL628">]
Robot.bot_names      #=> ["AP436", "KL628"]
Robot.delete(robbie) #=> #<Robot:0x000001019f4988 @name="AP436">
Robot.bots           #=> [#<Robot:0x000001019cd450 @name="KL628">]
Robot.bot_names      #=> ["KL628"]
Robot.reset          #=> []
c3po = Robot.new     #=> #<Robot:0x000001018ff8c0 @name="VO975">
Robot.bots           #=> [#<Robot:0x000001018ff8c0 @name="VO975">]
```

**Explanation**

- When the class is parsed, the class method `reset` is first created, then the line `reset` is executed. As `self => Robot` when that occurs, the class method `reset` is executed, initializing `@bots` to an empty array.
- The responsibility for saving and modifying a list of instances of `Robot` lies with the class. This list is held in the class instance variable `@bots`.
- Instance of `Robot` are created by invoking `Robot::new`, which allocates memory and then invokes the (private) instance method `initialize`.  Where is `new`? Since we have not defined it as a class method in `Robot`, there are two possibilities: it is inherited from one of `Robot`'s ancestors (`Robot.ancestors => [Robot, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]`) or it is an instance method of the class `Class`, as that is the class for which `Robot` is an instance (i.e., `Robot.class => Class`) Let's find out which: `Class.instance_method(:new) => #<UnboundMethod: Class#new>` (or `Class.instance_methods.include?(:new) => true`), `Object.method(:new) => #<Method: Class#new>`.  It's both! But that makes sense, because all classes are instances of `Class`, including `Robot`'s superclass, `Object`. `#<Method: Class#new>` returned by `Object.method(:new)` shows `new` is defined in `Class` (which can alternatively be seen with `Robot.method(:new).owner => Class`. Very cool, eh? If you didn't know this already, and can follow what I've said in this paragraph, you've just learned the essence of Ruby's object model!
- Suppose we add the class method `new`, shown below, to `Robot`. `super` invokes the class method `Object::new` (which is the instance method `Class#new`), passing any arguments of `new` (here there aren't any). `Object::new` returns the instance that it creates, which `Robot::new` in turn returns. Therefore, this method would simply be a conduit and and have no effect on the results.

  ```
  def self.new
    super  
  end
  ```
- We can make a small change to the above method to add a copy of the instance that is created by `Object::new` to the array `@bots`:

  ```
  def self.new
    instance = super
    @bots << instance
    instance
  end
  ```
- I have written this a little more compactly as:

  ```
  def self.new
    (@bots << super).last
  end
  ```
- I've used the method [Array#sample](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-sample) to randomly draw `PREFACE_SIZE` characters from `PREFACE` and `SUFFIX_SIZE` characters from `SUFFIX_SIZE`. `sample` samples *without replacement*, so you will not get, for example, "UU112". If you want to sample with replacement, replace the method `gen_name` with the following:

  ```
  def gen_name
    str = PREFACE_SIZE.times.with_object('') { |_,s| s << PREFACE.sample }
    SUFFIX_SIZE.times { str << SUFFIX.sample }
    str
  end
  ```
- I have created a class method `bots` to return the value of the class instance variable `@bots`. This could alternatively be done by defining a read accessor for `@bots` on `Robots`' singleton class:

  ```
  class << self
    attr_reader :name
  end
  ```
- When `Robot.reset` is invoked, what happens to all the instances of `Robot` it had contained? Will they be left to wander the forest, rejected and homeless? In languages like `C` you need to release their memory before casting them aside.  In Ruby and many other modern languages that's not necessary (and generally can't be done). Ruby's "garbage collection" keeps track of all objects, and kills off (after releasing memory) any that are no longer referenced by any other object.  Nice, eh?

Comment: This is not an answer. It's a _blog_. +1

Comment: I have a gem to automate this sort of tasks around naming objects and keeping record of the instances, it's `y_support/name_magic`. But you have an inspiring way of writing one-liner methods.

Comment: And `#sample` takes an argument... Time to hit the docs again.

Comment: Thanks, @BorisStitnicky. That' a cool and useful gem. One form of [Array#sample](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/Array.html#method-i-sample) takes no argument. There's even an example in the docs: `a.sample #=> 7`. It's been that way since at least 1.9.3.

Answer (score 2):

The task itself is not hard, but I don't like the way your code is organised. This is what I would do in the first stage:

```
class Robot
  class Name < String
    class << self
      def sign
        "#{[*?A..?Z].sample}#{[*?A..?Z].sample}"
      end

      def number
        "#{rand 1..9}#{rand 0..9}#{rand 0..9}"
      end

      def new
        super << sign << number
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And then:

```
Robot::Name.new
```

When constructing a list of names it is easy to check that they are unique. This is how I'd go about it:

```
class Robot
  class Names < Array
    def self.generate n
      new.tap { |array| n.times do array.add_random_name end }
    end

    def add_random_name
      name = Name.new
      include?( name ) ? add_random_name : self << name
    end
  end
end
```

And then:

```
Robot::Names.generate 7
```

Comment: Awesome response. Thanks a lot. But I am a beginner and your way of doing it is not for me for the  moment. Hopefully one day...

Comment: looks really awesome and laconically

Comment: @RadW2020 Don't say that to yourself. This is not an advanced stuff. Just the books don't teach you to begin using classes and namespaces like a human being from the get go.

Comment: A detail: in place of `rand( ?A.ord .. ?Z.ord ).chr` consider `P.sample`, after defining `P = (?A..?Z).to_a`.

Comment: Why not `Robot` is declared as a `module` ?

Comment: You correctly noticed that in my answer, I only use `Robot` as a module, I don't use special qualities of classes at all. But the OP used `class Robot` statement, and "robot" is a noun to boot, so it seemed to me as if the OP intended to make instances out of it. You know, "robot" is one of those favorite class names =) Every noob wants to write a robot =)

Answer (score 1):

I understand this isn't efficient, but this will work.

```
letters = [*'A'..'Z'] => 
numbers = [*100..999]
names = []
2.times{names.push(letters.shuffle.first)} => Randomizing array and choosing element
names.push(numbers.shuffle.first)
names.join => Creates a String object out of the array elements
```

This isn't pretty, but it gets the job done.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I automate Cary's approach with my `y_support/name_magic`:

```
require 'y_support/all'

class Robot
  ★ NameMagic

  def name_yourself
    begin
      self.name = "#{[*?A..?Z].sample( 2 ).join}#{rand 100..999}"
    rescue NameError; retry end
  end
end

3.times { Robot.new.name_yourself }
Robot.instances #=> [PR489, NS761, OE663]
Robot.forget "PR489"
Robot.instances #=> [NS761, OE663]
Robot.forget_all_instances
Robot.instances #=> []
Robot.new.name_yourself
Robot.instances #=> [IB573]
```